# Upgrade script continuously running and giving an error?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade-script

I write an upgrade script to alter on of my modules table.

My script is below
**mysql4-upgrade-3.0.8-3.0.9.php**

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE  {$this->getTable('rma_products')} ADD  `rp_radio_error_type` TINYINT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE  {$this->getTable('rma_products')} ADD  `rp_reason_for_return` VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE  {$this->getTable('rma_products')} ADD  `rp_product_activated` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE  {$this->getTable('rma_products')} ADD  `rp_failure_occur` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE  {$this->getTable('rma_products')} ADD  `rp_symptoms_of_failure` VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE  {$this->getTable('rma_products')} ADD  `rp_feedback` TEXT;
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

My config file is below

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MDN_ProductReturn>
        <version>3.0.9</version>
    </MDN_ProductReturn>
</modules>
.......
```

This runs once and what ever changes i expected is done.But when i refresh the website later site is down and giving me the error

> Ba:5:{i:0;s:242:"Error in file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Stainless-Safety-Solutions\app\code\community\MDN\ProductReturn\sql\ProductReturn_setup\mysql4-upgrade-3.0.8-3.0.9.php" - SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'rp_radio_error_type'";i:1;s:1108:"
>
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Stainless-Safety-Solutions\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
>
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Stainless-Safety-Solutions\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '3.0.8', '3.0.10')
>
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Stainless-Safety-Solutions\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('3.0.8', '3.0.10')
>
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Stainless-Safety-Solutions\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
>
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Stainless-Safety-Solutions\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
>
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Stainless-Safety-Solutions\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
>
> #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Stainless-Safety-Solutions\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Stainless-Safety-Solutions\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
>    #8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:28:"/Stainless-Safety-Solutions/";s:11:"script_name";s:37:"/Stainless-Safety-Solutions/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}

Why this is running repeatedly?

Comment: What is the version for your Module in the core_resource table in the Database?

Comment: 3.0.8, my current version is not upgrading

Comment: Did you go through the usual suspects: cache flushing, recompile, reindex ?

Comment: yes cache is disabled, Why my version is not updating?

Comment: Why don't you try adding new columns to your table like this:

`$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('rma_products'),'rp_radio_error_type', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TINYINT, 1, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
), 'Error Type');`

Comment: This is a deadlock. You have to either set your core_resource record to 3.0.9 manually and go on or revert the db changes and let the update run again to see if it updates your version correctly. If it still doesn't, you'll have to debug your update script.